How long does it take for mail from France to reach my address in India?
I applied for my bulletin n03 (French Police Clearance Certificate) from the official website by post on 5 November, 2024 but have not received it yet. I have to submit it for my Czech Visa. I enquired about it on the e-mail id of Casier Judiciaire and they said that it was dispatched on 13 Nov, 2024 and they said that they can't provide tracking information. I am assuming that they would have dispatched it via La Poste.
What is the expected time to receive this document by post to my address in India ? It is 26 November today and I am getting stressed. I enquired in my local post office on past Thursday and today and they have not received anything!
Can you please let me know if you know anything about it?

I edited the title, the question really has very little to do with the casier judiciaire, I guess it could be useful for any kind of official document you might want to get from France.

This discussion thread suggests 15 to 20 days is normal.
